# Why does an instance variable have a different value inside of a closure?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

```
func loadYelpComments(){
        guard let business = business else {return}
        guard let _ = tableView else {return}
        guard let businessID = business.id else {return}
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full

        HTTPHelper.getYelpComments(for: businessID, completionHandler: { data in
            let json = JSON(data)
            let reviews = json["reviews"].arrayValue.map({return $0.dictionaryValue})
            var commentDate: Date?


            for (index, review) in reviews.enumerated(){
                let userDictionary = review["user"]?.dictionary
                if let dateString = review["time_created"]?.stringValue{
                    commentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
                }

                let yelpComment = YelpComment(rating: review["rating"]?.intValue, userImageURL: userDictionary?["image_url"]?.stringValue, userName: userDictionary?["name"]?.stringValue, comment: review["text"]?.stringValue, commentDate: commentDate, commentPageURL: review["url"]?.stringValue)

                self.comments.append(yelpComment)
            }

            print("Number of comments: \(self.comments.count)") //Prints: Number of comments: 3"
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

            print("Number of comments: \(self.comments.count)") //This prints firt "Number of comments: 0"

    }
```

The `getYelpComments(for:completionHandler:)` class method is responsible for fetching JSON data from the Yelp API. To my surprise even though the `comments` instance array is being updated by appending new `YelpComment` objects to it, its `count` has different values inside and outside of the closure.

These comments are supposed to be displayed in a table view. What further confuses me is the fact that when I add `tableView.reloadData()` within the closure I get an `index out of bounds for an empty array` error but when I add the same line of code: `tableView.reloadData()` out side of the closure I get no error and `comments.count` equates zero. Any help would be much appreciated!

P.S. I don't know if mentioning this is going to make any difference but `data` is `@escaping`. I am also using `SwiftyJSON` and `Alamofire`.

UPDATE:

My table view data source methods are:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
            return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
        } else {
            return comments.count
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.YelpCommentCell, for: indexPath) as! YelpCommentCell
            cell.configureYelpCell(with: comments[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getYelpComments` is an async call. Print statement outside cloure execute  before the code in your closure runs. Post your `cellforRow` and `noOfRowsInSection` methods, i think those methods are causing the crash..

Comment: @Bilal updated my question with table view data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because the job of the `completion` block is to report to you when the network call is done. `HTTPHelper` is making a call to a server, which can take some considerable amount of time. It does not stop your program from executing, and just wait at that line: it goes to the next line, immediately, and calls `print("Number of comments: \(self.comments.count)")`, and you get 0, because the network call isn't done yet. Then, some time later, that whole `completion` block happens.

This is called an **asynchronous function**, and it commonly trips up people who haven't seen it before, but you see lots of it eventually, so it's worth reading up on.

The fact that you say "when I add tableView.reloadData() within the closure I get an `index out of bounds for an empty array` error", it sounds like one of your UITableViewDataSource functions that configures the table (`cellForRowAt`, `numberOfRowsInSection`), has an error in it somewhere.

Comment: updated my questions with my table view data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are not necessarily executed immediately at the point where you see them.

In your code, the `print` outside the closure will be executed before the `print` inside the closure. This is because `getYelpComments` is what is called an "asynchronous method". While you are waiting for the Yelp servers to respond, the code doesn't just sit there doing nothing. It continues to execute the code after the closure, printing that the count is 0.

After Yelp responds, the closure gets executed. And count, being 3, is printed.

As for why putting `tableView.reloadData()` causes it to crash, there is probably something wrong in your table view datasource methods. It is most likely an off-by-1.

Edit:

I think the fact that you write

```
if section == 0 {
    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
```

is weird. I don't know why you want to return the `super` implementation if the section is 0. Does your table view have multiple sections? If not, you should probably remove the check. If yes, then properly return a value for the first section.

Comment: updated my questions with my table view data source methods.

Comment: The first section is made up of static cells that is why I am calling super. The second section is meant to have dynamic cells where the comments are going to be.

Comment: @A.Jam If that's the case then I think you should do some debugging. Go to the line where the error occurred and print all the values on that line. These are basic debugging skills, you should probably learn them. Anyway, I think the discussion has moved away from the scope of this question. If you still can't figure out what's wrong after debugging, try to post another question.